# Passing non-variable object declaration

Tags: vba, excel

I have a method which contains a ParamArray parameter and was wondering if there was some special notation i could use in VBA to get the same effect as:

```
method val1, _
         val2, _
         new object(){prop1:=val11, _
                      prop2:=val12}, _
         new object(){prop1:=val21, _
                      prop2:=val22}
```

Its not pretty but should get the point acrossed.  Basically i am trying to translate the skills/logic i have learned to use in .Net, since 1.0, and try to incorporate a similar logic design in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the object construction shorthand then no, there is no direct equivalent.

If the member names are the same then you could use a factory function

```
method val1, val2, makeFoo(val11, val12), makeFoo(val21, val22)
.
.
.
function makeFoo(prop1 as string, prop2 as string) As clsFoo
   set makeFoo = new clsFoo
   makeFoo.prop1 = prop1
   makeFoo.prop2 = prop2
end function
```

`Optional` params would allow named arguments too `makeFoo(prop1:=val11, ...`

Comment: tyvm...i was hoping not to make a helper function but seems VBA hasnt developed over the last 20yrs.